# Does the word "house" include the land that surrounds it?

Tags: word-usage

Example:

[image]

Link: http://s0.geograph.org.uk/geophotos/03/76/64/3766499_abf79906.jpg

Can I say, "The bridge is **in** a country house?" Maybe it sounds strange? Like implying that the bridge is *inside* the house? Or maybe the word "house" can refer to the whole place?

Comment: Something else to note: "house" usually refers just to the physical structure ("We're building a house."), while "home" is used when emphasizing the domestic aspects of living: "They came out of the cold and back into the warmth of the home."

Comment: If your question is about the best way to describe the location of the bridge, it would be better to give your question a more accurate title and to give more details about the situation. Why do you want to describe the location of the bridge or it's relationship to the house? In what context will you use the language? As it stands, there seem to be four questions and it's unclear how to help you.

Comment: You can call it a country estate or just an estate as well. These words are also suitable according to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estate_%28land%29).

Comment: An estate comprises the **houses** and outbuildings and **supporting farmland and woods** that surround the gardens and grounds of a very large property, such as a country house or mansion.  (Wiki)

Comment: Noted linguist Graham Nash writes: "*Our house is a very, very fine house with two cats in the yard, life used to be so hard,
Now everything is easy cause of you*" http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/crosbystillsnashyoung/ourhouse.html I suspect that, colloquially at least, the yard is sometimes included in the house.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger: I saw a man at the park with a dog on a lead. Doesn't *necessarily* mean the dog was inside any part of the man ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the house is just the building. 
You'd normally say something like

> The bridge lies *in the grounds of* a country house

(the grounds means the land attached to the property).

If the grounds are very extensive, particularly if they include fields or other working areas rather than just gardens, you might instead refer to the "estate" attached to the house.

Comment: Maybe I can use something like country state? Is there something like that?

Comment: Country _estate_ (or, as above, the estate attached to the house) is fine.

Answer (score 5):

*House* always refers to the building.  The land and any associated structures (outbuildings, unattached garages, and, if you are lucky enough to have such, bridges) are called the [*curtilage*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtilage).

> In law, the curtilage of a house or dwelling is the land immediately surrounding it, including any closely associated buildings and structures, but excluding any associated "open fields beyond", and also excluding any closely associated buildings, structures, or divisions that contain the separate intimate activities of its own respective occupants with those occupying residents being persons other than those residents of the house or dwelling of which the building is associated.

Comment: While technically correct, *curtilage* is rarely used outside of legal or commercial contexts. There are only 24 instances of it in the BNC, and only 2 in COCA.

Comment: @choster -- you are [certainly correct](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo), *curtilage* is rarely used, but I would like to change that.  It is a perfectly cromulent word.  In particular, it fills a semantic need.

Answer (score 2):

[Premises](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/premises)  (*plural noun*) include:

> A house or building, together with its land and outbuildings, occupied by a business or considered in an official context (ODE)

As you can see from the definition, the word *premises* often refers to commercial or public property rather than private dwelling.

[Country seat](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/country-seat) (*countable*)

> a large house in the country with the land surrounding it, especially one that belongs to a member of the upper class: (Cambridge Dictionary)
>
> - Lady Castleton has a flat near Westminster, but her country seat is in Yorkshire.

[Manor](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/manor) (*countable*)

> a large old house in the country with land belonging to it, especially in Europe (Cambridge Dictionary)

[Property](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/property) (*countable*) means

> a building or area of land, or both together (Cambridge Dictionary):
>
> - He owns a number of properties on the south coast.

So you can say that the bridge belongs to that property in the picture

Answer (score 2):

You can say that the bridge is "at the house", but not "in the house". "At" includes the immediate surroundings, "in" specifically means within the building.

For example [The Garden at Chatsworth](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0711218374) ("A personal and horticultural tour of the 400-year-old gardens at Chatsworth House in Derbyshire"). No endorsement of the book intended, I haven't read it ;-)

For a big house with grounds, you might sometimes say "Chatsworth House" referring to the entire estate, but this is imprecise language and even so you still wouldn't say that the beehives (or whatever) were in the house.

The same applies to a smaller building: I might have a barbecue at my house, but normally not in my house. Again, in some contexts the house is taken to include the whole property. For example, if I say "I'm buying a house", someone might say "does it have a garden?" but they won't say, "are you buying a garden too?". It's understood that when I say "house", I'm buying a whole property which may or may not include a garden. If I say to a person "get out of my house and stay out", I don't mean "but feel free to hang out in the garden whenever you like", but if I say "I don't let my dog in the house", then the dog presumably is in the garden/yard/whatever.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the entries of the land registration office. But if it is a typical English manor your may assume that the building and the surrounding land belong together.

Answer (score 0):

I've often heard of a section of land (including primary residence and any building or feature of the land) being referred to as the property. For example, the apple tree is on my property.